# No normed space such that its dual is equivalent to $C^1[0,1],||,||_{\infty}$

Tags: normed-spaces

[image]

I have showed $C^1$ is not complete by taking $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}$ and showed is converges uniformly but limit doe not belong to $C_1$ (not differentiable at 0). Is this correct using the equivalent definiton in the question?

I said let x be a normed space. Then by a theorem its dual is complete. Suppose the dual is equivalent to C1... . This leads to a contradiction since dual is complete but C1 is not. So they can't be equivalent? How? Im not sure how to use the top paragraph of the problem

Comment: Then you can prove for any normed space $X$, its dual is complete

Comment: I said let x be a normed space. Then by a theorem its dual is complete. Suppose the dual is equivalent to C1... . This leads to a contradiction since dual is complete but C1 is not. So they can't be equivalent? How? Im not sure how to use the top paragraph of the problem

Comment: Ok, so after you new edit, you need to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent and $X$ is complete, then so is Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to show is that if $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces with $X$ complete and $Y$ not complete then they are not equivalent. Let $(y_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ with no limit point. Suppose there exists bounded linear bijections $B:Y\to X$ and $A:X\to Y$ with $A=B^{-1}.$ Then $(B(y_n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X,$ so it has a limit point $x\in X.$ Since $A $ is bounded and linear and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x-B(y_n)\|_X=0 ,$ we have $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}\|A(\;x-B(y_n)\;)\|_Y=\lim_{n\to \infty}\|A(x)-A (B(y_n))\|_Y=\lim_{n\to \infty}\|A(x)-y_n\|_Y$$ so $(y_n)_n$ converges in $Y$ to $A(x),$ a contradiction...You are correct that $C^1$ with the $\sup$ norm is incomplete. Weierstrass (19th century) showed that every continuous $f:[0,1]\to R$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials, and of course polynomials are $C^1$ functions.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a theorem which will come to the rescue:

**Theorem.** Every normed space over a complete field has a dual space which is complete under the operator norm.

$\mathbb{R}$ is, of course, complete.

Comment: Please read my edit.

Comment: Let $A : X \to C^1$ be an isomorphism. Let $x_n$ be the unique element satisfying $Ax_n = f_n$. Then the boundedness of $A^{-1}$ along with properties of norms will allow you to show that $x_n$ is Cauchy and yet has no limit.

Comment: Is the rest of my answer right? I don't see where to use the bounded linear maps definitions... and sequential continuity?

Comment: You have to write out the details of checking whether $x_n$ is Cauchy and converges. For example:

We claim $x_n$ is Cauchy. So fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f_n$ is Cauchy, there exists $N$ such that $n, m > N$ implies $||f_n - f_m|| < \epsilon/||A^{-1}||$. Then, for all the same $n$ and $m$, $$||x_n - x_m|| = ||A^{-1}f_n-A^{-1}f_m|| \leq ||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||f_n - f_m|| < \epsilon.$$ The existence of the operator norm $||A^{-1}||$ is where you need boundedness.

Comment: Is fn the function I defined? And the uniform convergence bit is not needed for this question?

Comment: Yes, it is. And uniform convergence is needed. When you say “converges uniformly but doesn’t have a limit,” you can’t have something converging uniformly to nothing, so what you really mean is “is uniformly Cauchy.” $f_n$ uniformly Cauchy means precisely that it is Cauchy under the uniform norm $|| \cdot ||_\infty$.

Comment: I wrote $||fn-f||_{\infty}$ $= sup... = \frac{1}{\sqrt(n)} \rightarrow 0$ as n tends to $\infty$. So it is Cauchy or no?